# Hide add to cart button when product visibility is hidden in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Every night I load in a CSV with my suppliers products. They remove and add products in every CSV. If a product is not in the CSV anymore and it was in the CSV before, my plugin will put the product visibility on hidden. This way the link still works, so no 404 errors in search console etc, but the product is not showing in my shop.

However, some customers still land on these links from different domains, i.e. google. They land on the "invisible product" and they have the possibility to click on the "in cart" button while the product is not available anymore.

Therefor my question: How can I (in functions.php?) make sure that when a product's visibility is hidden, the cart button is removed (a simple display: none; will do).

I use WP Import for importing the CSV and the way products are put on visibility:hidden is like this:

```
function my_is_post_to_delete($is_post_to_delete, $post_id, $import) {
     // Get an instance of the product variation from a defined ID
    $my_product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    // Change the product visibility
    $my_product->set_catalog_visibility('hidden');
    // Save and sync the product visibility
    $my_product->save();
    return false;
}
```

So I need something like this:

**If** `product_visibility` is '`hidden`' **then** remove add to cart button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `woocommerce_is_purchasable` dedicated filter hook when the product catalog visibility is "hidden", this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_product_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if( 'hidden' === $product->get_catalog_visibility() ) {
        $purchasable = false;

    }
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** If customer has a previous cart session with the product in it, it will be removed from it.

---

**Update** - For external (or affiliate) products try to use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_product_add_to_cart_button', 4 );
function remove_product_add_to_cart_button(){
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('external') && 'hidden' === $product->get_catalog_visibility() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. I will test this tomorrow as I'm not home now. Will let you know if it works!

Comment: I've tested your code and it doesnt work on my website. I think I know why because my shop doesnt have a quantity on products as it is an affiliate website. The cart button links customers to my partners hence I cant change the stock or put it on "out of stock".

Is there anyway you can make something that just hides the Cart button when a product is hidden? And put a placeholder that says "Not purchasable at this moment" or something like that.

Comment: @Kaboemm You should always give in your question all customizations and specificities related. The product property `is_purchasable` has nothing to do with quantity or stock management… see in [it's source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1484-1491)… So there is something else that is making trouble in your case as this works perfectly and it's something very classic that is used in this type of requirements…

Comment: Okay, sorry for being unclear. But could you transform your code into something like this:


`add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_product_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if( 'hidden' === $product->get_catalog_visibility() ) {
        **ADD TO CSS: .single_add_to_cart_button:display:none !important;**

    }
    return $purchasable;
}`

I'm not even sure if that's possible to do with php and functions.php but if it is, it would solve my problem. Thanks for your time

Comment: Okay I have found exact what is going wrong on my website at least (not with your code). When I put the woocommerce product on "Simple Product" then it works. When I put the product on "External/ Affiliate Product" it doesnt. 

Do you know how to rewrite the code so it works on the "External/ Affiliate Product"?

Thank you

(So It's not the WP Import plugin after all)

Comment: I found it, when the product is on hidden, the code works on the "External/ Affiliate Product" only when the URL is empty. So now I have to find out how to put the external URL to empty when the product visibility is hidden. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kaboemm I have added an update that could work in your case for your external products. Try it, it could work.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have put it on my website and unfortunately it doesnt work on my website. Is there any way you can remove the product URL when the product is hidden? That way it would solve my problem completely. Something like this
`$product->is_type('external') && 'hidden' === $product->get_catalog_visibility() then remove Product-URL`. Thank you

Comment: @Kaboemm This is because there are some other customizations somewhere made by your theme or a plugin.

Comment: Yes, im 100% sure you code works but I have a custom theme that doesnt support it for some reason. However, Im looking to remove the product url when the visibility is hidden. Because if the product-url is empty, woocommerce just doesnt show the cart button, so that would solve my problem. Is there any way you could make such a code for me? Or should I open a new thread for this?

Comment: I have found some other code online and mixed it with yours and I solved the problem. Thank you very much. The code I used to fix the issue is `/* make all products go to product page */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'woo_more_info_link' );
function woo_more_info_link( $link ) {
global $product; // switches link in all cases, i.e. in plugins
 
 if( $product->is_type('external') && 'hidden' === $product->get_catalog_visibility() ) {
        $link = $null;
    }

return $link;
}`

 It remove the product URL when the visiblity is on hidden.